# find text between 2 strings if not found blank

Tags: shell, sed, aix

I am trying to get string between device_uuid: and ,

d

```
device_uuid:xxx,
ptr
device_uuid:2,
```

command:

```
 sed -e 's/device_uuid:\(.*\),/\1/g' d
```

Output :

```
xxx
ptr
2
```

Expected output:

```
xxx
          == > blank as there is no pattern
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need some more advanced sed commands here:

```
sed 's/device_uuid:\([^,]*\),/\1/; tEnd; s/.*//; :End' <<DATA
device_uuid:xxx,
ptr
device_uuid:2,
DATA
```

```
xxx

2
```

The `t` command jumps to a label if the previous `s` command made a substitution, and the `:` command defined the label.

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands

May be easier to read with newlines instead of semicolons

```
sed '
    s/device_uuid:\([^,]*\),/\1/
    tEnd
    s/.*//
    :End
'
```